# grid alignment issue in semantic-ui-react

Tags: javascript, jsx, semantic-ui-react

I am using [semantic-ui-react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) to create a simple news-like layout with an image and text alongside but unable to fix the empty space issue.

Below is a screenshot along with details in computed panel. I am unable to figure out the cause of the empty white space(outside the padding area marked with green) in the first cell containing the image.

[image]

This is how my JSX code looks like -

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Grid, Image, Container, Header } from "semantic-ui-react";

export const SummaryList: React.SFC = () => {
  const items = Array.from(Array(10).keys());
  return (
    <div>
    {items.map((i) => 
    <Grid key={i} celled stackable>
      <Grid.Row centered columns={2}>
        <Grid.Column width={3}>
          <Image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/FIFA_series_logo.svg/1280px-FIFA_series_logo.svg.png" />
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={10}>
          <Container >
            <Header as="h3">quick brown fox scored a goal</Header>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
              commodo ligula eget dolor...
            </p>
          </Container>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
  )}
  </div>);
};
```

Comment: In your screenshot, in your developer window at the bottom, there is a box on the right side showing the padding. If you scroll down you will see the value for that padding. You can click the value to expand it and see exactly what class definition is giving you that padding. Or if you click the Styles tab above that, you can scroll through all styles being applied to that element individually.

Comment: I am aware of the dev window feature you mentioned but somehow it wasn't letting me point to the empty space and understand the settings contributing to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the extra space below was due to the long text in the second column while the cause of the extra space on left was due to the way semantic-ui arranges columns.

I did following things to fix the space on the left -

- moved the `Grid` out of the loop
- once I understood that `semantic-ui`
  comes with 16 columns, I assigned 12 column space to the text
  container and 4 column space to image.
- removed unnecessary
  `Container` within Grid.Column

Following helped me get rid of the extra space on the left -

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Grid, Image, Container, Header } from "semantic-ui-react";

export const SummaryList: React.SFC = () => {
  const items = Array.from(Array(10).keys());
  return (
    <div>
    <Grid key={i} celled stackable>
    {items.map((i) => 
      <Grid.Row centered columns={2}>
        <Grid.Column width={4}>
          <Image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/FIFA_series_logo.svg/1280px-FIFA_series_logo.svg.png" />
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={12}>
            <Header as="h3">quick brown fox scored a goal</Header>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
              commodo ligula eget dolor...
            </p>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
  )}
    </Grid>
  </div>);
};
```

I am still not sure how to make the text column dynamically adhere to certain size to ensure the image cell doesn't have to stretch too much. For now I adjusted the text size to align to not exceed image cell size.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your code and I don't have any white space.

[image]

So this could be caused by your body styles, try setting the margin and padding to 0, or if you have a container component holding it, the styles on that container could be the issue as well.

Comment: setting margin and padding to zero didn't help. turned out it was related to 2 things - the space below image was more to align with long text on right while the space on the left of image was more related to how semantic-ui arranges 2 columns in centre of a 16-column space.